# GET restapi in Codeigniter using cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, curl

I've a login form and the verification is done in controller verifylogin.php:

```
       function index(){
             $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','Username','trim|required');
             $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','Password','trim|required|callback_check_database');//check_database does the validation through database

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('login_view');
        }
        else{
            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $id = $session_data['id'];
            $url = "localhost/loginpage/index.php/home/$id";
            $this->verbs->get($url);
        }
    }
```

Then it goes to the verbs model to access the get method:

```
public function get($url){
      $curl = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $result = curl_exec($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      echo $result;
  }
```

Now the url is actually trying to access another controller which will display the homepage. $id is the corresponding users id.

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

        function userid($id){
            if($this->session->userdata('logged_in')){
                $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
                $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
                $data['posts'] = $this->user->blog_post_list($data['username']);
                $data['id'] = $id;
                $this->load->view('home_view',$data);
            }
            else{
                redirect('login','refresh');
            }
        }
}
?>
```

There is method known as userid in home controller. It'll check if the authentication is done and direct to the homepage. If not, we'll go back to login page. And if the user tries to access the homepage directly via the url (localhost/loginpage/index.php/home/$id) without logging in, he/she will be redirected to the login page. I've used routing to route home/$id to home/userid/$id.

Now the problem is, the get method is not working. It's returning a completely blank page. It is however going in the userid method (I echoed a random text and it turned up) but it's neither going to the home page, nor to the login page. Just blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: instead of $this->verbs->get($url); **try** redirect($url); directly

Comment: How do I use restapi if I use redirect? That defeats the purpose.

Comment: Oh! sorry my bad! didn't get the question at the first time!

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Why use redirect?